# RegEx - match all whitespaces (including line breaks) which are NOT the end of a preprocessor line

Tags: java, regex, minify, line-breaks, removing-whitespace

I would like to remove all unnecessary whitespace in a file, including line breaks, BUT only if that line break is NOT the end of a preprocessor line. The preprocessor commands are the same as in C though the language of the file is SQF, but that doesn't matter in this context. I'm doing this stuff in Java, but for reasons of readability, I'm putting my regex here in plain and not as Java strings.

This is an example of what a file might look like:

```
#include "someFile.ext"
#define IDD             idd_interact
#define ELEMENTS_COUNT  2

#define FRAME_X         ((1 - FRAME_W) / 2)
#define FRAME_Y         ((1 - FRAME_H) / 2)

_aNumber = 0;

if (_someVar == someGlobalVar) then {

};
```

I've tried it with this one: `\\s+(?!#)` but the result is this:

```
#include "someFile.ext" 
#define IDD idd_interact 
#define ELEMENTS_COUNT 2 
#define FRAME_X ((1 - FRAME_W) / 2) 
#define FRAME_Y ((1 - FRAME_H) / 2) _aNumber = 0; if (_someVar == someGlobalVar) then { };
```

After the last preprocessor line, the line break gets remove too. But I want that to remain, I want a result looking like this:

```
#include "someFile.ext" 
#define IDD idd_interact 
#define ELEMENTS_COUNT 2 
#define FRAME_X ((1 - FRAME_W) / 2) 
#define FRAME_Y ((1 - FRAME_H) / 2) 
_aNumber = 0; if (_someVar == someGlobalVar) then { };
```

I tried that with a negative lookbehind, but I could only come up with invalid regex (quatifiers and lookarounds don't seem to like each other):

```
(?<!(#[^\s]+\s+[^\s]+[^\n]*))[\s]
```

Now, I'm still rather new to RegEx, hence I'm pretty much at the end of my knowledge here. Is there a solution to that? I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
^((?!#).*?) *\n\s*| +$| +( )
```

which will give you this, when replaced globally, in multiline mode, with `\1\2`:

```
#include "someFile.ext"
#define IDD idd_interact
#define ELEMENTS_COUNT 2
#define FRAME_X ((1 - FRAME_W) / 2)
#define FRAME_Y ((1 - FRAME_H) / 2)
_aNumber = 0;if (_someVar == someGlobalVar) then {};
```

**BEWARE** This will replace whitespace in string literals. Regex is a poor choice for working on inputs with a complex nested grammar (like Java source code). I strongly recommend you look for existing, tested code minification tools that actually have a concept of what they are doing. Using regex on source code is like going into a very dark room with very sharp tools lying around. On roller skates.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm minifying SQF files, not Java files. The implementation of this is in Java and I'm aware of the whitespaces inside of string, don't worry :). The point is though to remove all whitespaces, including line breaks, UNLESS they are the end of a preprocessor line. By "whitespaces" I mean everything including line breaks. Sorry I wasn't clear about that, Java counts `\n` into `\s`.

Comment: A space and a newline occupy one byte each, what's the big deal?

Comment: It's about making the code less readable. I'm also minifying variable names, so basically the goal is to obfuscate the code without introducing "dummy code".

Comment: @jaySon Sounds rather futile. A simple code formatter will restore a readable format without problems. Anyway, see modified answer. You might want to replace `\t` with space beforehand.

Comment: Thank you! Might be futile, yes, but that's an additional effort somebody would have to make while it's no effort to me (once it's working). I also doubt there's a formatter which takes into account the special circumstances under which it's - for instance - not senseful to break a line after `{` or `}`, so I still consider it worth it. ;)

Comment: Well, good luck. Be very careful, it's easy to shoot yourself in the food with this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm aware that this is some pretty "dangerous" work and I'm not even sure if it will work out the way I want it. It's more of a hook for me to get into complex regex which I'll need sooner or later at work. Anyway, I'm either not understanding you correctly or I don't know better. But if I execute your regex, it's just grabbing the whitespaces, but I was expecting it to grab the whole line so I can replace it with the groups `\1\2`.

Comment: It does what it's supposed to do on https://regex101.com/r/uH5gB3/1 - since the regex is not overly fancy I don't see why it would not do the same in Java.

Comment: Even after all research and trying to get this to work my Java project, it just doesn't want to. I've tried numerous ways of manipulating that regex. Even this one `^((?!#).*?)\n` seems to remove the correct line breaks on regex101 (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/uH5gB3/4)), but doesn't do anything in my project. Seems like this problem is related to my lack of understanding Java regex.

Comment: @jaySon - Why don't you try to remove line breaks first. Then trim the interior separately.

Comment: I tried that just 3 minutes ago, lol. It becomes stranger the more I experiment around. For instance, `(\n)+` replaced by `\1` does the job on regex101, but in Java it has to be `code.replaceAll("(\\s)+", "$1")`, because `"(\\n)+"` matches each `\n` separately. 0_o

Comment: @jaySon -Try this `"^[^\\S\\r\\n]*(\\#.*\\r?\\n)|^[^\\S\\r\\n]+(?=\\#)|^\\s*\\r?\\n|\\r?\\n"` in multi-line mode, replace with `$1`

Comment: Wow, that works but holy sh... probably it would be more reasonable to do this step by step rather than in one long line. ^_^